# C# ParentForm.ActiveControl.Name

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (Operators.CompareString(this.ParentForm.ActiveControl.Name, this.Name, false) == 0)
{
base.Focus();
}
```

From What I have experience in VB6,the above code doesn't work because they are never equal if the users didn't change to the same name.

From Example, the UserControl Name is ucCalendar, When I drag to my From, the name will automatically change to ucCalendar1,even though I can change to ucCalendar but usually we won't do that.

I think the coder want to compare whether the UserControl is the only control or ActiveControl on the Form so that he can force to focus it.
I don't know this C# works or not. Please tell me.

Comment: Don't forget in that case `this.ParentForm.ActiveControl` **is** `this` (same object reference!!!) then `ActiveControl.Name` will compare to `this.Name`. That said, unless something (I guess) unwanted is happening, active and focused control should coincide

Comment: In VB6,In UserControl,UserControl.Parent.ActiveControl.Name and UserControl.Name has different name. My debug window shows "ucCalendar1" and "ucCalendar". @ISun

Comment: in WinForms when you're editing a `UserControl` then `Name` property contains its _name_ (class name). When you drop that control in another container (you use it) then name will be used to build an unique  name/id (even if it's not strictly required). When you access `Name` property from code (it doesn't matter where) then you'll always see name of its instance (then its _unique_ name). Forget about UI controls and think about it as classes and instances.

Comment: My old code is in VB6. UserControl.Parent.ActiveControl.Name is the instance on the form. My debug windows show "ucCalendar1" But in C#, this.ParentForm.ActiveControl.Name shows "ucCalendar". VB6 and C# give different result. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: And what this.Name shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the WinForms code saying that two controls can not have the same name. The reason you think that is that you're looking at it from the designer perspective, when you use the designer it won't let you have two controls with the same name just because it uses there as field names for them in the code, and as you probably know there can not be two fields / properties / variables with the same name in the same scope. As a matter of fact there is no need for the `Control`'s `Name` property to be anything.

Comment: I can say it is difference in VB6 and C#. But I haven't tested in C# because I don't know what Nameplace I should use. If you know, please tell me.